# In Paxos, what prevents multiple values from being chosen?

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

Say we have two proposers (P1, P2), one acceptor (A), and two learners (L1, L2).

What would prevent this sequence of events from occurring?

1. P1 initiates a round numbered 1. A agrees to participate, and reports that is has not voted on any proposals.
2. P2 initiates a round numbered 2. A agrees to participate, and reports that is has not voted on any proposals.
3. P1 asks A to vote for some value `v1` in round 1.
4. A accepts `v1` and tries to notify learners. L1 receives the message and declares that `v1` is chosen.
5. P2 asks A to vote for some value `v2` in round 2.
6. A accepts `v2` and tries to notify learners. L2 receives the message and declares that `v2` is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume this is Basic Paxos. Step (4) cannot occur - the acceptor A maintains in nonvolatile memory the largest promise it has made (the highest round it has agreed to vote on). At step (2), the max promise becomes 2. When A recieves P1's accept request in step (3) it will reject it because the accept request is from round 1 (this information is communicated in the accept request).